# How to zoom a picture while make it contained

Tags: html, css

my "wrapper" div is the most outlayer container. It consists of a picure and some text below.
I want to use CSS (not yet learned JS...) method to realize the effect that, when mouse hovering over the picure area, the picure zoom-in a little, but still remain inside the shadowed box.

Below is my html code and css code. It did give me zoom-in effect, but the picture just ... stick out, how can I fix this (hopefully without using Javascript)

-- html code --

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>shadow block | link with graphics and info</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sectionlink_pic.css">
</head>
<body>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/262508/pexels-photo-262508.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
            </div>
            <div class="infocontent">
                <h3>Home Security Blog</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

-- css --

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 400px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 3rem;
    box-shadow: 0.6rem 0.6rem 1.2rem #d2dce9, -0.5em -0.5em 1em #ffffff;
    padding: 2rem;
    z-index: 100;
}

.wrapper:hover {
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 4px lightgray;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper .image img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.wrapper .image:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

.wrapper .infocontent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Consolas;
    color: #36187d;
    cursor: pointer;
}

body {
    background-color: #f2f3f7;
    padding-top: 90px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Add [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to your image
- Add [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) (hidden) and border-radius to the image wrapper DIV:

```css
body {
  background-color: #f2f3f7;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  box-shadow: 0.6rem 0.6rem 1.2rem #d2dce9, -0.5em -0.5em 1em #ffffff;
  padding: 2rem;
  z-index: 100;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;   /* ADD */
}

.wrapper:hover {
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 4px lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*transition-duration: 0.2s; REMOVE */
}

.wrapper .image {
  overflow: hidden;            /* ADD */
  border-radius: 2rem;         /* ADD */
}

.wrapper .image img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* border-radius: 2rem;      REMOVE */
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 1s;    /* ADD */
}

.wrapper:hover img {          /* EDIT */
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.wrapper .infocontent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Consolas;
  color: #36187d;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/262508/pexels-photo-262508.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
  </div>
  <div class="infocontent">
    <h3>Home Security Blog</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot! I guess to achieve the animation effect, I can either ADD `transition: transform 1.2s;` in the style of `.wrapper .image img {}`  or, ADD `transition-duration: 1.2s;` in the style of `.wrapper:hover img {}` It seems both way give me same result, or is there any specific/better reason to your version of coding?

Comment: @Maggie For a better UX, say, if the entire "Card" is clickable, makes more sense to activate the animation on the entire card hover, not only on the image portion. That's at least how usually clickable cards are done in web/app design.